# weird transform or regexp issue

Tags: cucumber

I am playing around with cucumber and want to use transforms for readability. At the moment I am confused about the behavior of the following steps.

In one scenario (a) I have a step:

```
Given a player on 'B&O RR'
```

In another scenario (b) I have a similar step:

```
Given a player on 'Go'
```

My step definition looks like this:

```ruby
Given(/^a player on '(#{LOCATION})'$/) do |location|
  # do something with location
end
```

The transform is defined as follows:

```ruby
LOCATION = Transform /^[A-Z].*$/ do |location|
  raise "only once raised!"
  # lookup location and return it - if working
end
```

What I do not understand is why in (b) the transform is not executed. I tried the regexp in irb and it matched the strings of both steps but when I run the two scenarios containing these two steps only for the first (a) the transform is executed - proven with the exception.

Even when I run the second scenario alone the exception is not raised which IMO means that the transform is not triggered. What is going on here?

**Update:**

I still have no idea what is going wrong here, but at least I know how to work around:

```ruby
LOCATION = Transform /^'([^']+)'$/ do |location|
  # do stuff
end
```

IMHO this is also a better way to formulate the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, as for me, is to use regexp like:

```
LOCATION = Transform /^.*?$/ do |location|
  # do smth
end
```

In your case try this:

```
LOCATION = Transform /^[A-Z].*?$/ do |location|
 # do smth
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

`features/temp/temp.feature`

```
Feature: transform test

Scenario: a
    Given a player on 'B&O RR'

Scenario: b
    Given a player on 'Go'
```

`features/temp/step_definitions/temp_steps.rb`

```
Given(/^a player on '(#{LOCATION})'$/) do |arg|
    puts arg    
end
```

`features/temp/support/transforms.rb`

```
LOCATION = Transform /^[A-Z].*$/ do |arg|
    arg
end
```

Output:

```
cucumber --no-profile features/temp/temp.feature 
Disabling profiles...
Feature: transform test

  Scenario: a                  # features/temp/temp.feature:3
    Given a player on 'B&O RR' # features/temp/step_definition /temp_steps.rb:1
      B&O RR

  Scenario: b              # features/temp/temp.feature:6
    Given a player on 'Go' # features/temp/step_definition /temp_steps.rb:1
      Go

2 scenarios (2 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m0.030s
```

---

I agree your updated transformation regex is preferable, as it states that a "location" is what's included between single quotes.

Using the following modified step definition and transform, I get the same output as before:

`features/temp/step_definitions/temp_steps.rb`

```
Given(/^a player on (#{LOCATION})$/) do |arg|
    puts arg
end
```

`features/temp/support/transforms.rb`

```
LOCATION = Transform /^'([^']+)'$/ do |arg|
    arg
end
```